# Use localStorage to remember javascript alert

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When a user chooses an option in a select input, a javascript alert pops up. Using localStorage, how can I make my input remember not only the option the user selected, but also to pop the javascript alert?

Example: user selects option "3", javascript alert pops up. User leaves the page, then comes back. The select input shows "3" and the alert automatically pops up.

I know how to use localStorage to remember the option "3". Don't know how to use it in order to automatically pop up the alert.

---

WHAT I REALLY NEED TO KNOW: How to use localStorage to remember if a function was fired. If it was fired, fire it again.

---

My script:

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

var dropDown = document.getElementById("myselect");
dropDown.onchange = function() {
onchange=alert('You selected something!');
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H4kuk/10/

Thank you!

Comment: Just show the alert when you read from localStorage?

Comment: Check if item is set: ``if (localStorage.getItem("selectedItem") !== null) { //show alert} ``

Comment: WHAT I REALLY NEED TO KNOW: How to use localStorage to remember if a function was fired. If it was fired, fire it again. If function was not run, don't run it...

Comment: @Felix Kling - yes, show the alert if the value for "myselect" is taken from localStorage

Comment: @ adi rohan - working on that just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try manually trigger the change event if localstorage is not empty - `dropDown.onchange();`

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("myselect");
dropDown.onchange = function() {
    // Set the flag
    localStorage.setItem('itemWasSelected', true);
    alert('You selected something!');
};
// Check the flag on page load
if (localStorage.getItem('itemWasSelected')) {
    dropDown.onchange();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H4kuk/11/